# Spring Controller do some work after 10 seconds

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When a user sends a request, the information from the request will be sent to a remote web site. Then, I want to call an API to check if the request sent successfully. It returns nothing if I call it immediately, so the API should be called after some seconds.

Are there any methods to let Controller **sleep** a while, or make a **task** and automatic execution after some time?

Comment: Did you research Spring `@Scheduled()` annotation? It might be suitable for you somehow.

Answer (score 7):

To sleep for 10 seconds, you can use `Thread.sleep()`:

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

But be careful with this method, it will block your thread and not let it handle other user requests until the timeout expires. It might lead to thread pool exhaustion (and finally to request timeouts) if you have many such requests running in parallel.

To execute some task after 10 seconds, you can use `Timer.schedule()`:

```
new Timer().schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code here
        }
    }, 
    10000
);
```

This call will return immediately and execute the check later in a separate thread. This approach is much more safe and scalable.

If you need more control on the delayed tasks, you can also use `ScheduledExecutorService`. It will allow you to define the size of the thread pool that will execute your tasks, to cancel pending tasks, to obtain results from them etc.:

```
// Create a pool of threads to execute checks
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);

// In the request handler:
ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
    // Your code here
}, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I thought about this method, but I wonder if it is ok in Spring Controller. does it effect other operations?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is a bad choice because it blocks the thread for quite a long time, not allowing it to handle other requests. But it's the simplest solution if you need to return the result of the check to the user synchronously. Otherwise, `Timer` is preferable because it returns immediately and lets you release the request handling thread quickly.

Comment: I tried `Timer` but it throw `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`. Because I use `OpenSessionInView` for hibernate, when the request finished, the database session closed too. So I can't operate database.

Answer (score 4):

Let me please summarise. If you need response immediately you may use @Async annotation on your service/controller method (note, you need to enable it by @EnableAsync configuration annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Next, autowire embedded spring scheduler:

```
@Autowired 
private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
```

And finally, schedule taks execution:

```
taskScheduler.schedule(
    () -> {/*task code*/}, 
    new Date(OffsetDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
);
```

More details about async processing and scheduling in spring you may find [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Comment: Hi, where should I put the taskScheduler.schedule to work? In which controller method?

Comment: In method you want. For initial question like: 
public void acceptCall(Req req) {
taskScheduler.schedule(
    () -> {/*call back */}, 
    new Date(OffsetDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
);
}